# How does facebook call the native iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, native

I want to know how does facebook native app call my native iOS app.
Facebook requires App bundle id, app store id, and url sufix (optional). What I want to know is: how facebook process these information and open my native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [custom URL schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18).

What you basically do is define a "url" for your app so you can access it from anywhere in the OS (using that URL). What FB does, when it opens Safari to authenticate you for example, is specify YOUR app's custom url as a callback URL, so when it finishes, it calls that url and that redirects it back to your app.

You can test this by setting a custom URL for your app, firing up Safari, and typing that url. It will jump straight to your app.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/12/22/using-app-url-schemes-in-ios/).

Comment: glad to hear that! what was the problem?

Comment: omg sorry I haven't seen the message. The problem was that the url that I was using was not correct. the url should be fbxxxxxxx://bundle
Where: xxxxxx - is the app id on facebook and bundle is the bundle id of the native app

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to set any of that to have the Facebook app send you back to your own app. The SDK does that automatically.

Setting the app bundle ID in your Facebook app (in the Facebook developer center) allows the Facebook app to send the user immediately back to your app if they've already given permission to your app before. It's just a nice feature, but it's not necessary for everything to work.